# Python object content keys description in function signature

Tags: python, comments

Is there a possible way to describe the content of a returned object in function comments ?

This seems doesn't work, I don't have access, with IntelliSense, to the content of the returned object properties.

Example :

```py
def parse_configuration(path_to_json: str, path_to_schema: str):
    """
    Parse a configuration file and check it with a json schema
    :param path_to_json: Path to the configuration file (json format)
    :param path_to_schema: Path to the json schema (json format)
    :return: {"name", "version", "port", "address", "database_path"} or ParseError exception
    """
    with open(path_to_json, "r") as jsonFile:
        with open(path_to_schema, "r") as schemaFile:
            json_object = json.load(jsonFile)
            json_schema = json.load(schemaFile)
            if validate_json(json_object, json_schema):
                return json_object
            else:
                raise ParseError
```

Comment: How do you know what it's going to return? It takes paths to two files, there's nothing that guarantees any particular result beyond that the JSON matches the schema; you don't know what that schema is going to describe.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is not very clear, my question is more about how to describe an object returned by a function and not how it will be returned. I use json schema to be sure of the content of the object (with the required attribute) or return a parse error execpetion when it's not the case

Comment: My point is that you _can't_ describe that object, because the schema and source are dynamic. You'll get back what the schema defines, but that's not know at the time of writing the code.

Comment: Oh okay I was missing the point, thanks !